# Flutter: FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage never execute in iOS

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to execute some code in onBackgroundMessage when app is in background or killed.

I am getting push notifications as aspected but onBackgroundMessage function is never executed in iOS. It works perfectly in Android devices.

Here is my code:

```
Future<void> _backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async{
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  dynamic isCall = message.data['status'];

  print(isCall);

  if(isCall == 'call'){
   //.....
  }else{
    NotificationHandler.flutterLocalNotificationPlugin.cancelAll();
  }

  FirebaseNotifications.showNotification(message.data);
}



Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_backgroundHandler);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I also add APNs and add capabilities Background Modes and Push Notifications. Tested on real device.

[image]

What should have to do to execute FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage function in iOS?

Comment: Have you tried it on simulator or real iOS device? On simulator it won't work as far as I know.

Comment: I tried on real device.

Comment: Have you completed all [these steps](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration)?

Comment: @PeterKoltai yes. Push notification works as expected, but onBackgroundMessage function is not executed in iOS.

Comment: Same here. did you solve this problem? what was your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `content-available` to `true` in your notification payload from backend.
This value let OS know that some data is available with the notification and allow that callback to be executed even when your app is in terminated state.

Answer (score 1):

## Client

for ios:

1. foreground - `onMessage`;
2. background - `onBackgroundMessage`;
3. terminated - `onBackgroundMessage`.

### BUT

if app was terminated, first notification will be handled with `getInitialMessage`, because first notification wakes up the app

## Server

exapmle of config:

```py
       messaging.Message(
            token=recipient['fcm_token'], data={**message_data, 'user_id': str(recipient['user_id'])},
            notification=messaging.Notification(
                title=message_data['title'], body=message_data['body'], image=message_data['image'],
            ),
            fcm_options=messaging.FCMOptions(analytics_label=message_data.get('analytics_label', None)),
            apns=messaging.APNSConfig(
                payload=messaging.APNSPayload(
                    aps=messaging.Aps(
                        content_available=True,
                    ),
                ),
                headers={'apns-priority': '5'},
            ),
        )
```

need `content_available=True` and maybe `headers={'apns-priority': '5'}`